# Does netbeans run slower when lines of code is longer?

Tags: netbeans

Does netbeans run slower when you have more lines of code? It just seems to be grinding to a halt at the moment and im modifying a file with quite a lot of code. And wanted to know whether that was the cause

Comment: I haven't noticed a problem such as this. Can you give a bit more information about your PC's spec?

Comment: Must be due to resources then, it's running on remote desktop as well which doesn't help